# How to pass image string value to the imageslide using swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, image, swift2

I am developing a app using swift 2.2 in my app am using image slide show by refering this link https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow i want to pass images string with concatenating url....

images string am getting from the json data:

```
{

   "Values Of Image":[{

   "image":"apple.png,jewels.png,gun.png,mango.png"

   }]

}
```

this is just an example json data but am getting data like this

now i can able to seperate the string now i want pass the value to alamofire source(imageslide)

coding in controller:

in view did load:

```
let MyImageSlide =  json["Values Of Image"][0]["image"].stringValue
        let parts = MyImageSlide.componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        for numbers in parts{
            print("image String:\(numbers)")
         let alamofireSource = [AlamofireSource(urlString: "https://www.something.com" + numbers as String)!]
         self.SecondImageShow.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
         self.SecondImageShow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.UnderScrollView
         self.SecondImageShow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
         self.SecondImageShow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
         self.SecondImageShow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
         self.SecondImageShow.setImageInputs(alamofireSource)
        }
```

total images in my response is four...but it fetches last image only...
help me to fetch all the images

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It only show the last because you call the `setImageInputs` inside the loop.

`setImageInputs` should call the array of image source. Your changes should be something like below.

```
// create array of image sources
var images = [InputSource]()

for numbers in parts{
     let alamofireSource = AlamofireSource(urlString: "https://www.something.com" + numbers as String)!
    images.append(alamofireSource)
}

self.SecondImageShow.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
self.SecondImageShow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.UnderScrollView
self.SecondImageShow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
self.SecondImageShow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
self.SecondImageShow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill

// load the array here
self.SecondImageShow.setImageInputs(images)
```

Refer the detail class here https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow/blob/master/ImageSlideshow/Classes/Core/ImageSlideshow.swift

Comment: am getting error at images.append(alamofiresource) i.e..argument [AlamofireSource] does not conform to the expected type input store

Comment: try change to `var images = [AlamofireSource]()`

Comment: gives same error as  images.append(alamofiresource) i.e..argument [AlamofireSource] does not conform to the expected type AlamofireSource

Comment: i forgot to remove the `[ ]` from `[Alamofire .. ]` inside the loop. check the updated code